# Reuse legacy .net 4.7.2 libs with EF 6.4 + Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramerowk with a .net core 3.1 app?

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, .net-core

I'm trying to figure out how to reuse a legacy .net 4.7.2 library with both a legacy .net 4.7.2 app and a new .net core 3.1 app.
The legacy lib depends on EF 6.4 and [Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-core-2-0-preview-2/#user-content-reference-net-framework-libraries-from-net-standard) nuget packages.

My initial take was to multi-target both .net 4.7.2 and .net standard 2.1 to be able to consume the lib from the new .net core 3.1 app alongside with the old .net 4.7.2 OWIN app.

While EF 6.4 supports .net standard 2.1, `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework` seems to target .net only, resulting in NU1702:

> package Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework was resolved using
> '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2' instead of the project target framework
> '.NETStandard,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible
> with your project.

It *may* be ok for a library targeting .net standard [to reference a .NET Framework library that happens to only use types within the .NET Standard API set](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-core-2-0-preview-2/#user-content-reference-net-framework-libraries-from-net-standard), so chances are `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework`, apparently built for .net 4.5, may still work.

I haven't been able to find a replacement for that package targeting .net standard, so the question is: is this situation ok and, if not, may be better ways exist to reuse such legacy libs in .net core apps?

Comment: "apparently it's okay for a library targeting .net standard to have dependencies targeting .net 4.6.1 and below," - uhhh, not really - where are you seeing that?

Comment: "I haven't been able to find a replacement for that package targeting .net standard" - you're probably better-off disassembling the assembly and recompiling it for .NET Standard, imo.

Comment: added link to https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-core-2-0-preview-2/#user-content-reference-net-framework-libraries-from-net-standard

Comment: Right, but this part is important: "The supported scenario is referencing a .NET Framework library that happens to **only use types within the .NET Standard API set**"  - that's not the same thing as the _unqualified_ statement you made about targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1 in general, because there are _huge swathes_ of .NET 4.6.1 that aren't in .NET Standard 1.x.

Comment: right, updated the question accordingly

Answer (score 1):

> how to reuse a legacy .net 4.7.2 library with both a legacy .net 4.7.2 app and a new .net core 3.1 app. The legacy lib depends on EF 6.4 and Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework nuget packages.

You can't. `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework` can't be used in a .NET Core app.

You can use `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core` and `Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore` in a .NET Core app, but only with EF Core, not EF 6.

IE Oracle doesn't support the combination of EF 6 and .NET Core.